# Java: Get User Input from JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Currently I'm using the following code to display a text field to user and retrieve the input from user.

```
public void getInputFromUser ()
{

    String input = null;
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setColumns(50);

    textField.setVisible(true);


    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 75);
    frame.add(textField);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.requestFocus();
    frame.addWindowListener(null);


    textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

              String text = textField.getText();

              System.out.println(text);
           }
        });
```

This works fine. However the issue is:

• I want to be able to get the input when user closes the dialog as appose to when user hits enter

• I want to stop the execution of the program until the user enters something and closes the dialog. Right now the program continues to run even before user enters anything in dialog / text box.

Comment: That doesn't sound intuitive for most dialogues. But what you want to block them is a modal type window. Maybe [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) will help.

Comment: Consider using `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(..)` instead of the frame.  It seems to fit this need well.  See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1):

I know a one simple way, how you can do it. When I need make something like it, I use JDialog always. If you set JDialog as`modal`, It stop execution of the program, if the JDialog is visible. I updated your code below:

```
 public void getInputFromUser ()
 {
    String input = null;
    JTextField textField = new JTextField("sadsadasd");
    textField.setColumns(50);

    textField.setVisible(true);

    JDialog jd = new JDialog();
    jd.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    jd.setSize(300, 75);
    jd.add(textField);
    jd.requestFocus();
    jd.setModal(true);
    jd.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("I am here");

    textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            String text = textField.getText();

            System.out.println(text);
        }
    });
}
```